# ASP.NET Clickable Div in Repeater

Tags: c#, jquery, html, css, asp.net

I have a problem with a clickable div, I know how to make a clickable div, however, the div I want to make clickable is in a repeater. I tried linkbutton instead of div with the commandname but its not quite suitable for me.

The thing I'm trying to do is make the div clickable because I need control it from code behind, maybe there is a solution with the jQuery or c# both of them okay for me.

The div I talked about is divproblem.

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rpAlbumler" OnItemCommand="rpAlbumler_ItemCommand">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <div class='<%#Eval("Kategoricss") %>' runat="server" id="dvKategoriler">
                    <div class="fw-portPreview">
                        <div class="img_block wrapped_img fs_port_item">
                            <a class="featured_ico_link" href="portfolio_post_fullscreen_ribbon.aspx">
                                <asp:Image runat="server" ID="imgkapak" ImageUrl='<%#Eval("Kapakpath") %>' />
                            </a>
                            <div class="bottom_box">
                                <div class="bc_content">
                                    <h5 class="bc_title">
                                        <asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="hplnkAlbumIcerik" Text='<%#Eval("Abaslik") %>'></asp:HyperLink>
                                    </h5>
                                    <div class="featured_items_meta">
                                        <span>
                                            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblKategoriler" Text='<%#Eval("Kategorihazir") %>'></asp:Label></span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div id="divproblem" class="bc_likes gallery_likes_add">
                                    <i class="stand_icon icon-heart"></i>
                                    <span>
                                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblAlbumBegeni" Text='<%#Eval("Albumbegenisayisi") %>'></asp:Label></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="portFadder"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: This code is not enough to reproduce the problem. Please, try to better describe the problem and provide a sample that can realy reproduce it.
If the problem is with your jQuery code, it should be provided too.

Comment: On click what functionality you want ? Redirect or pop up ? You can use ScriptManager to put a script (having onclick code) from code behind to div and then do whatever you want

Comment: Actually when the users click the div I need to send the data to database because of the repeater, I can't reach the div from the code behind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really simple your `<div>` cannot be hooked up to the click event in jQuery using ID because the ID appears multiple times in the repeater so you need to bind the div to a click event using the `class` attribute:

```
$(".bc_likes").click(function () { });
```

Secondly to talk to the code behind from the jQuery click event you can use `$.ajax` and make a call to a C# `[WebMethod]` where you can write your code behind logic.

**.Code behind:**

```
public partial class RepeaterExample : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            var p1 = new Product { ID = 1, ProductName = "Banana" };
            var p2 = new Product { ID = 2, ProductName = "Apple" };
            var p3 = new Product { ID = 3, ProductName = "Orange" };
            Repeater1.DataSource = new List<Product> { p1, p2, p3 };
            Repeater1.DataBind();
        }
    }

    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static string ServerCall(int id)
    {
         return "Server response.Processed ID - " + id;
    }

}

public class Product
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
}
```

**.ASPX:**

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $(".bc_likes").click(function () {
                var id = $(this).data('id');

                $.ajax({
                    url: 'RepeaterExample.aspx/ServerCall',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    data: JSON.stringify({ id: id }),
                    method: 'POST',
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert(data.d);
                    }, error: function (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <ul>
            <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <li>
                        <div id="divproblem" class="bc_likes gallery_likes_add" data-id='<%# Eval("ID") %>' style="border:1px solid red;">
                            <i class="stand_icon icon-heart"></i>
                            <span><%# Eval("ProductName") %></span>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <SeparatorTemplate>
                    <hr />
                </SeparatorTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
        </ul>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Good answer.  Also, I would hasten to add the reason behind not being able to wire up jQuery click events is that it will only apply to the first element with that ID that is found on the page. 

Also, if you're going to be adding any more of them dynamically after page load, use `$(".SOMEPARENTELEMENT").on("click", ".bc_likes", function(e) { //on click behavior });` to ensure that further dynamically added elements will be clickable.  I say this only because I've run into this problem before.